# Multisim delta-delta connection

Tags: transformer, simulation, multisim, delta

I try to simulate a delta-delta transformer connection in Multisim but I get an error, why, I don't know. My diagram is as below:

[image: Here the circuit]

Here are the errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Read the first error message!!!!!

Comment: You need to have ground reference, probably, on each side of the transformer.

Comment: @Luiz Oliveira and Andy aka, I tried it before post the question, but it is not about ground. Even if I place ground to every phase, I get same error. And if I change the primary section with wye connection, I get no error, even if there is no ground...

Comment: I added some details to question @Andyaka

Comment: Put a ground on the common connection of the three load resistors. It must be there. It may still throw some errors but you must have this ground node specified.

Comment: @Andyaka, yes as you said, I got almost same error after put the ground.

Comment: @Wtow, can you try to put a ground only in one point of the primary (only in node 1) and "skip initial operating point solution"? (it works in LTSpice, but some kind of inrush can occur).

Comment: I put the ground as you said and ran the simulation on different mods but the result is same. [Here the mods](https://www.multisim.com/help/simulation/simulation-types-and-settings/)

Comment: You can try this SPICE net list https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhR86nrv-ZA7jL8R2_MicUkLsREOGg?e=5s8n4h

Comment: @LuizOliveira That works, thanks for your helps. But what is difference between my drawn and your codes ?

Comment: I can see only the ground. Maybe there is also something related to the method for solving, if you try to compute the DC operation point, it crashes. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This circuit is really tricky. It is very likely that the issue is related to grounding. Undoubtedly, at least one ground point is required.

Checking the errors you posted in the question, I was able to elaborate the following:

On [this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhR86nrv-ZA7jL8R2_MicUkLsREOGg?e=5s8n4h) LTSpice circuit, I used yours 'node 1' to position the ground, but there are certainly other possibilities. However, even LTSpice fails if you try to calculate the DC operating point, ie you need to start with the initial variables zeroed (some inrush will happen and depending on the circuit constants it can take long to damp).

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to install 3 resistors of 1 Ohm each to achieve convergence of the solution
[image]